# How fast should a web response be?

Tags: web-development, optimization

I've heard a few times that every extra [number1] milliseconds it takes to process a web request and return a response will lose you [number2] percent of users.  Is this just "conventional wisdom," or have there been actual studies on the subject?  And has there been found to be a lower bound to this phenomenon, like "[number3] milliseconds is fast enough, improving further than that won't hold any more users"?

Comment: Your links seem to have gotten misplaced.

Comment: http://glinden.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/new-google-study-on-speed-in-search.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should read Jakob Nielsen thoughts on this topic.

http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html

> 0.1 second is about the limit for having the user feel that the system is reacting instantaneously, meaning that no special feedback is
>   necessary except to display the result.
>
> 1.0 second is about the limit for the user's flow of thought to stay uninterrupted, even though the user will notice the delay. Normally,
>   no special feedback is necessary during delays of more than 0.1 but
>   less than 1.0 second, but the user does lose the feeling of operating
>   directly on the data.
>
> 10 seconds is about the limit for keeping the
>   user's attention focused on the dialogue. For longer delays, users
>   will want to perform other tasks while waiting for the computer to
>   finish, so they should be given feedback indicating when the computer
>   expects to be done. Feedback during the delay is especially important
>   if the response time is likely to be highly variable, since users will
>   then not know what to expect.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the sort of information I was looking for!